# Hide Port Numbers after redirect from IIS to Apache

Tags: windows, apache, iis

I am running IIS 6.0 and Apache 2.2 on a Windows Server 2003 (dedicated)

I have a default website on IIS which is required on port 80 (default). Apache has been setup to listen on 8080. I need IIS for one sytem and Apache for another.

I have setup an IIS redirect to URL to forward any request to www.myotherdomain.com to www.myotherdomain.com:8080 (all works fine)

The problem is I don't want the port number showing in the address bar. Is there any way i can mask it?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a slightly different approach to acheive desired effect.

You could make one server 'forward' requests onto the other - this is known as a 'reverse proxy', and is different to a redirect. It's invisible to the user.

Can you switch Apache to port 80 and IIS to 8080?

If so, you can make Apache forward certain requests to IIS, based on part of the URL.

Apache has a module called mod_proxy. See the example labelled 'Reverse Proxy'

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

Note: you can also use Apache's mod_rewrite to acheive the same thing, and with more flexibility.

Note2: I don't know if IIS has a similar feature.